# Convert largefiles to normal files

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, large-file-support

I have a repository where the trunk does not contain any largefiles. In my working branch, I previously added and committed some binaries as largefiles. Now, I don't want them to be largefiles anymore. I haven't merged into trunk yet.

I've tried removing the files entirely, then committing, then adding the files using `hg add --normal`, but this results in my diff containing both the standins in .hglf as well as the binary files. Is there any way to get rid of the standins without making a new branch and grafting changes?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new branch off of the ancestor I had originally branched off from, then merging in my messed up branch. Before committing this merge, I excluded all of the largefiles in question. Then, I created a new commit, committing the largefiles as normal files using the `--normal` flag.

When I creating a pull request to the ancestor with this new branch, no standin files appeared in the diff and thus no largefiles were merged in, while preserving the commit history from my messed up branch.